# El tipo HomeController ya define un miembro denomidado Index MVC C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Soy nuevo en esto, estoy consumiendo un webApi desde un proyecto de MVC c#, en mi pagina de index consumo el metodo que me muestra todos los registros de una tabla de mi BD, pero tengo un error en el metodo index, asi tambien tengo otro metodo para agregar registros y no tiene problema mi metodo, este es el error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el metodo agregar no tiene problemas y es casi lo mismo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor, en lugar de imágenes, copia y pega el código original en la pregunta. Gracias.

Comment: Se recomiendo que leas acerca de la [sobrecarga](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobrecarga_(inform%C3%A1tica)), ya que es un concepto realmente importante en la [programación orientada a objetos](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programaci%C3%B3n_orientada_a_objetos), y te va a llevar a solucionar tu problema.

Answer (score 1):

En tu Controlador `HomeController`, tienes definidos dos métodos `Index()` con los mismos parámetros.

Para que en principio te funcione, debes **eliminar uno de ellos**. Por sentido común, y ya que no realiza ninguna acción relevante **elimina la Acción**:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {                       
         return View();
    }
```

Aún así, ten en cuenta que puedes tener múltiples Acciones con el mismo nombre en el Controlador, siempre y cuando reciban diferentes parámetros (**sobrecarga**).

Si te das cuenta, la Acción `Create()` tiene dos métodos diferentes y no te da error, esto es por que reciben diferentes parámetros:

```
    public ActionResult Create() // Sin parámetros
    {                       
         return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Create(EmpModel e) // Con parámetro EmpModel
    {                       
         return View();
    }
```